# Setting up sitemaps of multisite network in google search console

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, multi-subdomains

I have a multisite network and each site has its own sitemap.
e.g. the main site's sitemap is at `main-site.com/sitemap-index.html` and the subdomain's sitemap is `main-site.com/site1/sitemap-index.html`

I have set up search console, with `main-site.com` as a property and `main-site.com/sitemap-index.html` for the sitemap.

I would like to submit the sitemap for each subsite to Google so:

- Should I need to create a different property for each sitemap?
- Or do I add each subsite sitemap in the same section where I put the sitemap for the main site?

Comment: The subdomain's sitemap is in a subdirectory?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister yes it is